# Error creating variable in R

Tags: r, paste, cat

I am pasting several words together but I need the output without the quotation and index. For that I am using the following code:

```
condition_2<-cat(noquote(paste("S1_images", "[[1]]",sep="")))
```

When I run it, I get the right result on the terminal: `S1_images[[1]]`. But, if I check check the variable `condition_2` to be sure that the text has been saved, I get the following output

`NULL`

This is creating a problem  since I need that variable to be used as reference later on the code.

-- EDIT --

I need the index `[1]` out since I want to use `condition_2` as a reference in another line. If I do not remove it, this is what happens:

`training_r<-rasterize(training,condition_2, field=test$_ID)`

Which output is:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ?rasterize? for signature ?"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "noquote"?
```

If I remove it (using `cat`), this is what happens:

`> training_r<-rasterize(training,condition_2, field=test$ID)`

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ?rasterize? for signature ?"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "NULL"?
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think the issue comes from `cat` which is forcing the console to print the text, http://127.0.0.1:14718/library/base/html/cat.html, why are you using that function? Note: you can also reduce the `paste(..., sep = "")` to `paste0(...)`. If you are just looking to assign the value to `condition_2` then just use `condition_2<- noquote(paste0("S1_images", "[[1]]"))`

Comment: I am using `cat` to remove the `[1]` that is added to the output of my code. If I run the code without `cat` the output would be `[1] S1_images`

Comment: ok, but why do you need that to be gone? I'm pretty sure that number is just part of the R console - indexing the object that has been called - and is not "attached" to the value `condition_2` For example, if you pass rep(coniditon_2, 1000) to the console, the start of each row gives a number which is the position of the first instance of that row

Comment: I have edited the question to add more information

Comment: could you humor me, try with `condition_2<- paste0("S1_images", "[[1]]")` - so no `noquote` or `cat` - and tell me what happens

Comment: Here is the output of that:   `condition_2<-paste0("S1_images","[[1]]")`
Then, `training_r<-rasterize(training,condition_2, field=training$Crop_ID)` And now the output would be: 
`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ?rasterize? for signature ?"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "character"?`

Comment: I think the problem is that the function `rasterize` needs a `raster` object has argument. In my case , I have to change the raster of reference depending on my condition. When using `condition_2` in the function `rasterize` it sees it as a character and not as a raster object. If this is the case, any sugestion?

Comment: Can you try this - `condition_2 <- parse(text = paste0("S1_images", "[[1]]"))`? and then while calling `rasterize` use `rasterize(training,eval(condition_2), field=test$_ID)`.

Comment: see the documentation here on the arguments passed to `rasterize` specifically the "function"

Comment: @Prem, smart solution using `parse` & `eval`. Now it is working, thanks for your help. Feel free to post the solution as an answer so  I can approve it.

Comment: I don't understand why you use "cat". I tried running your code step by step. It was the only thing that gave me an error. Something happens between "cat" and "noquote". And if you don't use "cat" you still have no quotation.
BTW, what is your sessionInfo()?

Comment: In my first attempt I was using `cat` to remove the index `[1]`. I needed to do that since I was using the output of that condition as a reference in another line of my code. I am using R. 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Never mind, it seems like @Prem did it best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable using

```
condition_2 <- parse(text = paste0("S1_images", "[[1]]"))
```

and then while using this variable you can wrap it with `eval` e.g.

```
rasterize(training, eval(condition_2), field = test$_ID)
```